# Can the profile2 fields in registration be made obligatory?

Tags: users

I have a profile2 profile type in which I want to expose some fields to the user when registering.

Is there a way to make a field obligatory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, as you do with any field make it as **Required field**.

Comment: As well, make sure the 'Show during user account registration' is checked in the profile settings.